# Bounding a ratio that depends on a discrete probability distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose $p=(p_1,p_2,...,p_N)$ is a discrete probability distribution. Are there any assumptions we could make about $p$, say $1/(C_1 N) \leq p_i \leq C_2/N$ for every $i$ and $C_1, C_2>1$, that would enable us to bound from above the following ratio
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N p_i \big|\frac{1}{p_i}-N \big|^3}{\big(\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{p_i} -N^2\big)^{3/2}}$$
by a quantity that **neither depends on** $N$ **nor on** $p$ ? The problem with separately bounding the nominator from above and the denominator from below is that the denominator equals zero when $p$ is the uniform distribution and I cannot afford an assumption about $p$ that excludes $p$ being close to uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done.  Consider $Np_i = 1 + \frac{\epsilon_i}{\sqrt N}$, where the $\epsilon_i$ are small, and $\sum\epsilon_i = 0$.  Then $\frac1{Np_i} \approx 1 - \frac{\epsilon_i}{\sqrt N} + \frac{\epsilon_i^2}N$.
Then
$$ \left(\sum\frac1{p_i} - N^2\right)^{3/2} \approx \left(\sum \epsilon_i^2\right)^{3/2} $$
Also
$$ \sum p_i |\tfrac1{p_i}-N|^3 \approx \sum \frac1N |\sqrt N\epsilon_i|^3 = \sum \sqrt N |\epsilon_i|^3 .$$
So if we choose $\epsilon_1 = -\epsilon_2$, and $\epsilon_i = 0$ for $i \ge 3$, we see that the upper bound is larger than a constant times $\sqrt N$.

However, an upper  bound of order $\sqrt N$ can be proven.
\begin{align} \sum p_i |\tfrac1{p_i}-N|^3 &= \sum p_i^{-1/2} |\tfrac1{\sqrt{p_i}}-N\sqrt{p_i}|^3 
\\&\le \left(\sum p_i^{-1/3} |\tfrac1{\sqrt{p_i}}-N\sqrt{p_i}|^2\right)^{3/2}
\\&\le \sqrt{C_1 N} \left(\sum |\tfrac1{\sqrt{p_i}}-N\sqrt{p_i}|^2\right)^{3/2},\end{align}
and
$$ \sum \left(\frac1{\sqrt{p_i}} - N\sqrt{p_i} \right)^2 = \sum\frac1{p_i} - N^2.$$

Comment: Thanks ! Your counterexample seems to set $p_i=1/N$ for $i\geq 3$. What if none of the $p_i$ is equal to $1/N$ ? I did a lot of simulations with $p$ very close to uniform (but none of the coordinates exactly equal to $1/N$) and the ratio seems to be bounded, independently of the dimension $N$.

Comment: You could also take $\epsilon_i$ for $i \ge 3$ to be much smaller than $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$, and the counterexample will still work.